# Logarithmic curve fit in data

Tags: fitting, logarithmic-scale

I have the following data which are the theoretical:

```
cycles={70954, 55331, 43274, 33942, 26701, 21065, 16667, 13225, 10524, 8398, 
6721, 5394, 4341, 3503, 2835, 2300, 1871, 1526, 1248, 1023, 841, 693, 
572, 473, 393, 326, 271, 226, 189, 158, 132, 110, 92, 77, 64, 53, 44, 
36, 29, 23, 17, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}

sigma={500, 505, 510, 515, 520, 525, 530, 535, 540, 545, 550, 555, 560, 
565, 570, 575, 580, 585, 590, 595, 600, 605, 610, 615, 620, 625, 630, 
635, 640, 645, 650, 655, 660, 665, 670, 675, 680, 685, 690, 695, 700, 
705, 710, 715, 720, 725, 730, 735, 740, 745, 750, 755, 760, 765, 770, 
775, 780, 785, 790, 795, 800, 805, 810, 815, 820, 825, 830, 835}
```

and here the experiment points.

```
ExpDatMPa={835.03, 823.4, 793.06, 704.82, 609.83, 602.62, 598.09, 595.61, 
591.55, 584.71, 551.18, 541.23, 539.32, 385.34, 385.21}

ExpDatN = {23, 69, 43, 328, 5941, 4506, 1876, 7898, 27015, 19154, 
  130885, 431405, 84036, 1003250, 113442}
```

I plot both of them using `ListLogLinearPlot`

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{Transpose[{cycles, sigma}], 
  Transpose[{ExpDatN, ExpDatMPa}]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Cycles [N]", "Stress Mpa"}, PlotRange -> Axis, 
 Joined -> {True, False},PlotLabel -> "S-N Cyclic Fatigue Life at R = -1 "]
```

[image]

Now I want to draw a logarithmic curve fit through the experimental points.
I have searched through the help on *Mathematica* but could not find something which would help me understand how I could do it. Can somebody give me a hand?

Comment: Check [NonlinearModelFit](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html?q=NonlinearModelFit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to take the log of the data, and do a linear fit:

```
 fit = FindFit[ Transpose@{Log@ExpDatN, ExpDatMPa} , 
       a + b  ln , {a, b}, ln ]
```

or fit to the log expression:

```
 fit=FindFit[ Transpose@{ExpDatN, ExpDatMPa} , a + b  Log[n] , {a, b}, n ]
```

(same result)

```
 Show[{ListLogLinearPlot[{Transpose[{ExpDatN, ExpDatMPa}]}, 
      AxesLabel -> {"Cycles [N]", "Stress Mpa"}, PlotRange -> All, 
      PlotLabel -> "S-N Cyclic Fatigue Life at R = -1 "],
      LogLinearPlot[a + b Log[x] /. fit , {x, 1, 10^6}]}]
```

[image]

your plot is red because PlotRange->Axis is not a valid option, by the way.